# Is there a javascript to check if another script has been activated?

Tags: javascript, html, menu, navigation, sidebar

I have been building a pop out menu for a website with HTML and Javascript, and I've managed to get a button to create a pop out div container with a button inside that closes it. Eventually there will be more buttons and all kinds of things, but I'm keeping it simple for now. Let me say that Javascript is not my strong suit. The problem I am having now that I've got all the buttons working properly and hiding the div, is that while the div disapears when I push the "close" button, the elements within it do not. I'm hoping I can make an if else script that will either hide or remove the elements within the pop out div when the "menu" button (which causes the pop out div to appear) is activated. To even start figuring out that, I'll need a script that can detect if the script that runs when the menu button is pushed is active. My apologies if I'm explaining this poorly, but the relevant code is pasted in below, hopefully that will help. Is there a script that can detect if another script is running that can then activate an if else script? As a bonus, does anyone have any ideas about a script that can hide (or remove) elements conditionally? Both together would be lovely :)

Here is the code:
**HTML** and **Javascript**-

```
<div>
    <script>
        function sidebar() {
            x = document.getElementById("sbb")
            x.style.width = "0";
            x.style.position = "relative";
            x = document.getElementById("sba")
            x.style.width = "200px";
            x.style.top = "0px";
            x.style.bottom = "0px";
            x.style.position = "absolute";
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function closesb() {
            x = document.getElementById("sba")
            x.style.width = "0";
            x.style.position = "relative";
        }
    </script>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100; z-index:3">
        <button type="button" onclick="sidebar()">MENU</button>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="sba" id="sba">
            <button type="button" onclick="closesb()">CLOSE</button>yellow</div>
        <div class="sbb" id="sbb">yellow</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**-

```
.sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.sba{
    width:200px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    background-color:#787878;
    opacity:.75;
    position:absolute;
    height:10em;
}
.sbb{
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:200px;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**NOTE:**

1- the word "yellow" in divs "sba" and "sbb" is just to determine the location of the divs on the page, as the pop out menu is done in layers.
2- the button scripts are the only scripts running on the page, and the whole website.
3- I am only interested in answers in Javascript and HTML, and that work on all browsers, or nearly all, right now, please.

Comment: is there any specific reason you are not using `display:none`to hide the div??

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/jpEqt/1/

```
function sidebar() {
        x = document.getElementById("sba")
        x.style.display = "block";
    }

function closesb() {
        x = document.getElementById("sba");
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

<div class="sba" id="sba" style="display:none">
```